# python3 incorrectly configured?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, python-venv

I have an OL7 Linux machine behind a firewall and with access only to python 3.6 in the repo.

Python 3.6 was installed in 2018 but never used and now I need to import some modules, but could not because the version requirement isn't met.

To this end I downloaded and manually installed 3.11.2, apparently successfully:

```
server:user:/home/user $ python3 --version
Python 3.11.2
```

According to root I have a good setup:

```
server:root:/usr/local/bin $ python3 -m ensurepip --default-pip
Looking in links: /tmp/tmp0p21jg5t
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (65.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (22.3.1)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

However I can't run pip in either of the two recommended ways:

```
server:user:/var/tmp $ python3 -m pip --user install numpy-1.24.2.tar.gz
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed

server:user:/var/tmp $ pip3 install --user numpy-1.24.2.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

When I tried to run `python3 -m ensurepip --default-pip` as my user it failed because I lack write permission to `/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools-65.5.0.dist-info` so I tried to create a venv:

```
server:user:/var/tmp $ python3 -m -venv /home/user/python3_venv
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named -venv
```

Clearly there is something wrong with my environment, but what?

In terms of install all I've run is:

```
  119  make clean
  120  ./configure --enable-optimizations
  121  make
  122  make test
  123  make install
```

I had to abandon make test because of the lack of internet access but otherwise it seemed OK.

I'm not sure it is relevant but `/usr/local/bin` is in my user's PATH, but isn't in the default root PATH used at build time.

Other things I've tried is to remove the 3.6 environment, including pip, but that hasn't helped.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the site-packages directory was built with 700/600 permissions for files/directories.

The fix is to grant the missing permissions:

```
server:root:/var/tmp $ find /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
seerver:root:/var/tmp $ find /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages -type f -exec chmod go+r {} \;
```

Now running as my user I get:

```
server:user:/var/tmp $ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.3.1
setuptools 65.5.0
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

I think there may be other files I can't see, if I find any I'll update this answer.